# Grails remoteLink vs <a>

Tags: grails, gsp

I'am building a simple app that gets a list of items from db (around 3000 rows for now), renders a table with item names then displays item specs whenever we clic on a specific item.
I've have noticed a small performance issue when rendering the html table with g:remoteLink instead of the the old basic a tag.

I have a controller that gets data and renders a template

```
def items = sql.rows("select * from items")
render (template:'itemList',model:[result:items])
```

i also have a simple index file

```
<body>
<g:remoteLink controller="items" action="getItems" update="itemList">Items</g:remoteLink>
    <div class="body" style="width: 1000px;">
        <div id="itemList"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and my itemList template (slow, around 4s)

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" id="mytable">
    <g:each var="item" in="${result}">
    <tr>
    <td><g:remoteLink controller="items" action="getItemSpec" update="itemDetail" params="${ [itemcode: item.itemcode] }">
        ${item.itemcode}</g:remoteLink></td></tr>
    </g:each>
</table>
```

another version of the itemList template (fast, around 400ms, using the generated link from remoteLink)

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" id="mytable">
    <g:each var="item" in="${result}">
    <tr>
    <td>
<a onclick="jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',data:{'itemcode': '${item.itemcode}'}, url:'/myApp/items/getItemSpec',success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#itemDetail').html(data);},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}});return false;" href="/myApp/items/getItemSpec?itemcode=${item.itemcode} "> ${item.itemcode}</a>
</td>
</tr>
    </g:each>
</table>
```

Is there a way to make the rendering faster using remoteLink instead of using the a tag?

Thanks !!

Comment: Do you see the same performance problem if you run with `grails run-war`?  The performance hit may just be a side effect of GSP reloadability when using `run-app`.

Comment: What Andrew said plus the fact that rendering 3000 rows without paging data is generally not a great idea.  The tag does have to process and that is a lot of processing at once.

Comment: There's a small difference between run-app and run-war, but the a tag is still faster. I know that displaying 3000 row is not a geat idea. The next step is to implement something like jqgrid / datatables, because i will need sorting / filtering. I'm comparing rendering with / without ajax calls to see which one is doing best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things I would suggest considering...

1.) Loading 3,000 of anything in view is generally not a good idea.  Try thinking about what your really trying to achieve by showing this amount of data.

2.) If ultimately you plan on using something like jqgrid or datatables don't focus on something that one of this tools may essentially do differently.  Go right to the end solution you want and then tweak from there.

3.) Think about all the code being generated on the page and how much is actual being used.  If you generate 3,000 links and a user is likely to only click on 5 or 10 maybe you use some jQuery to handle dynamic loading of the link on row click. This should speed up the rendering because there is less HTML for the browser to display.

4.) Lastly, frameworks like Grails among several others allow you to easily do things which *may* come at the sacrifice of some performance.  Getting the most out of something may require you to by pass a lot of convenience.

Enjoy!  Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree with all the points above except the first one because it doest fit on project i'm working on. The third one did give me a hint, so i created a js function that wraps the js contained in the "onclick" event, it did pretty much was i was looking for, but it's a bypass as you said in point 4. @michael-j-lee